# Refactoring an each loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, each

UPDATE: I managed to refactor the code a bit, but it's still a nested loop.

I think I've figured out a way to improve the code using `map` and `keep_if`. I don't know that it's ideal though, because it's still a nested loop.
    output = {}

```
array.map do |a|
  output[a[0]] = another_array.dup.keep_if do |b|
    a[1].include?(b["name"])
  end
end
```

This is a bit of a n00b question. I'm trying to figure out how I can refactor a nested each loop like the one below so that I am not declaring extra variables that I won't need later and so that my code runs quicker.

```
some_array = [["one", 2, 3], ["two", 3, 4], ["three", 4, 5]]
output = {}

some_array.each do |a|
  current_group = []

  another_array.each do |b|
    current_group << b if something == true
  end

  output[a[0]] = current_group
end
```

The `output` is returned as a hash of arrays. `some_array` is a nested array where the first element in each sub-array is a string and `another_array` is an array of hashes.

Comment: You probably want [`.inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Comment: How come your outer loop is not using `a`?

Comment: what is `something`?

Comment: `something` just represents a condition that is either true or false.

Comment: Do you mean `...if something == true` (which is the same as `...if something`)? Also, what is your expected or desired output?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I changed it to `==`. The output is a hash where each key-value is an array of hashes.

Comment: I managed to refactor it a bit (See update above), but it's still a nested loop, which is the principle problem with it.

Comment: Readers obviously do not understand your question. To get useful answers you need to include `another_array` and `something`, so that the problem is complete and self-contained. Also show the (specific) hash you want as output for the given input. Until you do that, your question will go nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're doing from that code - what is `group`?  How does the condition tie `some_array` and `other_array` together?  But in general, if you want to build a new array or hash, the idiom to reach for is something with `inject` (a.k.a. `reduce`).  The pattern is this:

```
output = some_array.inject({}) do |partial_output, item| 
   ...
   new value of partial_output after this loop iteration
end
```